# determine if python lists are the same lists or merely equivalent lists

Tags: python, list, compare

Suppose I have this code:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,2]
def equivalentButDifferent(list1, list2):
    # list1 and list2 are lists
    return <is list1 and list2 the same or merely equivalent>
```

How do I return *True* for `equivalentButDifferent(a,b)` but *False* for `equivalentButDifferent(a,a)`?

Comment: Compare `is` and `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The == or != operators compare the values for equity.
In this case:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> a == b
True
>>> a != b
False
```

That is, a and b are equals.

is and not is compares the values for identity (if they are the same).

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> c = a
>>> a is b
False
>>> a is c
True
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  This actually helps me understand this distinction, which has been causing me some confusion in (what I thought were) a number of other areas too.  I still think like a 90's C-engineer (pointers, etc), so my Google-fu didn't pick up on the previous question as I didn't realize that was the topic.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help you. =)

Answer (score 3):

As @jonrsharpe said in the comment, this would be the function:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,2]
def equivalentButDifferent(list1, list2):
    return list1 == list2 and list1 is not list2
```